# Metric space contractions

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Consider $(\mathbb{C}^n ,||\cdot||_{1})$ where $||x||_{1} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} |x_{i}|$ and $d_{1}(x,y) = ||x-y||_{1} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n |x_{i} - y_{i}|$.

I want to find a condition such that when $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, f(x) = Ax + b$ is a contracting map.

Note $||\cdot||_{1}$ is norm base $1$ and $A = (a_{ij})$.

I can see that it contracts if $||A|| < 1$. Is their any other conditions I missed that make this a contracting map? Does $A$ have to be anything specific?

Comment: And what do you mean by $\|A\|$?  Does $f$ really map from $\mathbb C$ and not $\mathbb C^n$?

Answer (score 0):

If by $\|A\|$ you mean the *operator norm* of $A$ with respect to this norm, then yes, you're set.  If you mean $\|A\|_1 = \sum_{i,j = 1}^n |a_{ij}|$, then you are incorrect.

Comment: Well $A \in M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$

Comment: That doesn't answer the question of what you mean by $\|A\|_1$. Different textbooks and people use different notation.